# Maximizing between a number and 0 in sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've written a query in SQL which yields several columns, including one, called NPV, which has both positive and negative numbers in it. I would like to turn all the numbers less than 0 into the number 0 using some SQL command. Below is my code. I'm hoping someone could help me with this!

```
SELECT  TRADE_TYPOLOGY, CONTRACT_ID,  DATE(START_DATE) as START_DATE, 
MATURITY, NPV, COUNTERPARTYNAME
        FROM
        (SELECT PACKAGE_ID, CONTRACT_ID, max(DATE(substr(MATURITY_DATE, 0, 5) 
|| '-' || substr(MATURITY_DATE, 5,2) || '-' ||   substr(MATURITY_DATE, 7, 9)) 
) as MATURITY, TRADE_TYPOLOGY, PORTFOLIO, COUNTERPARTY,START_DATE, 
COUNTERPARTYNAME,INTERNAL, sum(CONTRACT_NPV) as NPV
        FROM 
        (SELECT *
        FROM "Trade Details 2" 
        WHERE INTERNAL="N"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only one condition then go with [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT  
  TRADE_TYPOLOGY, 
  CONTRACT_ID,  
  DATE(START_DATE) as START_DATE, 
  MATURITY, 
  IIF(NPV < 0, 0,NPV) as NPV 
  COUNTERPARTYNAME
FROM -- your remaining query
```

Not sure if `IIF` supports in SQLite or if you have multiple conditions, then go with `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT  
  TRADE_TYPOLOGY, 
  CONTRACT_ID,  
  DATE(START_DATE) as START_DATE, 
  MATURITY, 
  CASE WHEN NPV < 0 THEN 0 ELSE NPV END as NPV 
  COUNTERPARTYNAME
FROM -- your remaining query
```

Comment: `CASE` *expression*, not `case` statement.  And `case` is ANSI standard and supported in basically all databases.  `IIF()` is just for compatibility with MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

Something like 'IIF(NPV < 0, 0)' should work, there is also the select case variant.